# Do SQL Server have the utility same as Oracle Wrap Utility?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, scripting

i have made a useful scripts in my environment and i want to wrap the script same as Oracle Wrap utility can do. is there any other way to the same in sql server?

Comment: Might be helpful to link to the documentation on the Oracle Wrap utility and / or explain what it does / how it works.

Answer (score 1):

### Oracle Database

Oracle's Wrap Utility is limited to encrypt only contents of the following types:

#### 19.0 Documentation

- Package specification
- Package body
- Type specification
- Type body
- Function
- Procedure

<sup>***Reference:** [PL/SQL Source Text Wrapping](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-source-text-wrapping.html#GUID-C37788E2-0F5D-430B-8D9C-6CD708223C93) (Oracle | Database PL/SQL Language Reference)*</sup>

#### Microsoft SQL Server

If you have a look at the individual `CREATE ...` statements for the available objects in Microsoft's SQL Server then you will observe that the following objects can be encrypted:

1. Functions

   ```
    CREATE FUNCTION .... WITH ENCRYPTION...
   ```

   <sup>***Reference:** [CREATE FUNCTION (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (Microsoft Learn | SQL)*</sup>
2. Procedures

   ```
    CREATE PROCEDURE .... WITH ENCRYPTION...
   ```

   <sup>***Reference:** [CREATE PROCEDURE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (Microsoft Learn | SQL)*</sup>
3. Triggers

   ```
    CREATE TRIGGER .... WITH ENCRYPTION...
   ```

   <sup>***Reference:** [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (Microsoft Learn | SQL)*</sup>

Other options for other Microsoft SQL Server objects may be available, but I guess you get the general idea.

Comment: thank you so much John for the insight. Appreciate it !

Comment: @zulnasir If you think my answer is helpful, then I would appreciate an accept or at least an up-vote to my answer. Thanks.